# Apache Downloading Laravel index.php After PHP7 to PHP7.4 Update

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I installed php7.4 (previously running 7.0.33) on my server and now every time I try to visit my website, it just downloads the laravel index.php file instead of displaying it.

I understand that this means something is not configured correctly with apache (I don't have Nginx), but I can't figure out what! I've been looking for hours!

This is what I did to install (based on this guide https://www.cloudbooklet.com/upgrade-php-version-to-php-7-4-on-ubuntu/)...

```
 sudo apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
 sudo apt install software-properties-common
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt install php7.4
 sudo apt install php7.4-common php7.4-mysql php7.4-xml php7.4-xmlrpc php7.4-curl php7.4-gd php7.4-imagick php7.4-cli php7.4-dev php7.4-imap php7.4-mbstring php7.4-opcache php7.4-soap php7.4-zip php7.4-intl -y
 sudo apt install php7.4-fpm //(I don't think this was needed)
 sudo a2dismod php7.0
 sudo a2enmod php7.4
 sudo service apache2 restart
```

I am able to make my website work again by doing this... (but the PHP version reverts back to 7.0 of course)

```
 sudo a2dismod php7.4
 sudo a2enmod php7.0
 sudo service apache2 restart
```